# How can I locate and repair a circuit break in an older home?

Tags: electrical

I am planning on from the breaker box to energize the circuit at one of the fixtures in that circuit.

I have a new 100' roll of copper 10ga house wiring (2 wires+ground)... too big??....

How best to tie-in to the circuit..thanks

Comment: Is the rest of the circuit already wired?  Can you post photos of the inside of the junction box you want to "tie in" at?

Comment: Maybe give us a drawing of what's going on, in addition to the pictures. What are you providing power for? #10 wire is pretty hefty for most things, so you may be able to return it and pick up a less expensive roll of cable.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour]. You've asked multiple rather vague questions here, which goes against our rules of engagement. Please reduce your question to one specific topic and provide enough detail for us to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're *always* allowed to upsize and use larger wire than is required.  (one footnote, if you upsize conductors you must upsize ground in proportion, but that'll happen automatically in your case).

The only snag is connecting the uber-fat wire to terminals; in that case you may need to pigtail to smaller wire sizes, however all the wiring in the circuit including those pigtails must be big enough for the breaker.  So on a 20A breaker you can't pigtail down to #14 just because it fits in the backstabs.

**However, I am uncomfortable with your premise that "there must be a wire break in the walls"**.  90% of the time when I hear this, the person doesn't know what the problem is; they arrive at "wire break in the walls" *because they can't think what else it might be*.  I strongly discourage this.  Failure inline along a cable is *extremely rare*, and basically does not happen unless incompetent construction has been done along the cable's route.   We get lots of "didn't check the neutral lug in the panel", and occasionally a "wire broke off inside its insulation".  But that always happens inside panels or junction boxes.

We also get a few misidentified cables; i.e. the 2 ends you think are the same cable, aren't. Remember all neutrals and grounds are connected to each other at cable bus bars, grounds are often (legally) connected elsewhere as well, and neutrals are sometimes (illegally) connected elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 1):

10 AWG is OK, but generally for standard 15A (14 AWG or 12 AWG) and 20A (12 AWG), you use smaller wire, because it is cheaper and easier to work with.